# Programa só funciona uma vez

Tags: python-3.x, login

Fala galera, estou desenferrujando python e estou montando um programa simples que aos poucos vou dividir os módulos, acrescentar tratamentos etc...
O problema é o seguinte: no código abaixo, o programa só funciona uma vez. Eu crio o usuário e no fim ele me exibe que o usuário foi criado e a chave:valor e chama a função inicio, porém quando seleciono uma nova opção, o programa simplesmente termina. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

```
    # cadastar usuario 
    # login
    # sair do sistema
    # mostar tela
    # mostar dados do usuario

    import sys
    bd = {}

    def cadastar_usuario (user = 0, pwd = 0):
      usuario = input("Por favor, digite um nome de usuário: ")
      senha = input("Digite uma senha: ")
      bd.update({usuario: senha})
      print("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso! \n ", bd, "\n\n")
      inicio()

    def entrar():
      print("Usuario entrou")

    def mostrar_dados():
      print("Mostrando dados")

    def sair():
      print("Até a proxima")
      # sys.exit()

    def inicio():
      select = int(input("Escolha uma opcao: \n"
      "1 - Cadastrar usuario \n"
      "2 - Entrar \n"
      "3 - Mostrar dados de usuarios \n"
      "4 - Sair do sistema \n"))
      return select
    opcao = {1:cadastar_usuario, 2:entrar, 3:mostrar_dados, 4:sair}
    opcao[inicio()]()
```

Comment: Não deveria ter um laço pra chamar a função `inicio()` até digitar `4` para sair?

Comment: Sim, eu vou implementá-lo, mas mesmo sem o laço, como estou seguindo os caminhos para ele não finalizar, ele deveria funcionar, correto? Exemplo, se eu seleciono a opção 1, depois digito um usuario e senha, ele exibe e chama a funcao inicio, porque quando escolho outra opção, ou até mesmo a 1 novamente ele finaliza? Ou estou errado e isso é somente a falta do laço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é simples dentro da sua função cadastra você chama a função inicio que retorna o valor de select para nada. Como foi a chamada opção na última linha do seu código que desencadeou essas chamadas ela retornará a partir desta linha, o que resulta na finalização do programa.

```
# cadastar usuario 
# login
# sair do sistema
# mostar tela
# mostar dados do usuario

import sys
bd = {}

opcao = {1:cadastar_usuario, 2:entrar, 3:mostrar_dados, 4:sair}

def cadastar_usuario (user = 0, pwd = 0):
  usuario = input("Por favor, digite um nome de usuário: ")
  senha = input("Digite uma senha: ")
  bd.update({usuario: senha})
  print("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso! \n ", bd, "\n\n")

  opcao[inicio()]()

def entrar():
  print("Usuario entrou")

def mostrar_dados():
  print("Mostrando dados")

def sair():
  print("Até a proxima")
  # sys.exit()

def inicio():
  select = int(input("Escolha uma opcao: \n"
  "1 - Cadastrar usuario \n"
  "2 - Entrar \n"
  "3 - Mostrar dados de usuarios \n"
  "4 - Sair do sistema \n"))
  return select

opcao[inicio()]()
```

Com essas pequenas alterações seu programa deve funcionar. Porém eu aconselho fortemente criar um laço principal que realiza o input e chama as funções. Um código desta forma será completamente problemático ao realizar manutenções futuras tente deixar as coisas mais claras.

Comment: Obrigado Joannis, vou testar aqui e estudar um pouco mais para entender melhor. Obrigado pelos conselhos, vou melhorar. Inclusive já implementei o laço.

Comment: Se puder depois de testar colocar como correta eu agradeceria. Evite essas chamadas conhecidas como goto, você pode acabar criando um looping infinito indesejado que vai perder horas para resolver.